# material ui :nth-child() and nextjs is not working?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Hello and thank you for reading my question..

I am using NextJS for my personal website and material ui. Now I render dynamically some pieces of data and I want some children to be shown on a specific position using :nth-child but it doesn't seem to work.

The parent component is position relative and the element I am targeting is absolute. I tried different versions of it and some people's post here but it doesn't seem to be working.

Thank you very much :)

```
 '&: first-child': {
      top: '35%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },
    '&: last-child': {
      top: '20%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },

or

'&: nth-child(1)': {
      top: '35%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },
    '&: nth-child(2)': {
      top: '20%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },
'&:nth-child(1)': {
      top: '35%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },
    '&:nth-child(2)': {
      top: '20%',
      zIndex: 4,
    },
```

````js
 <Box
        sx={{
          display: 'flex',
          flexWrap: 'wrap',
          flexDirection: 'column',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          position: 'relative',
          gap: 4,
        }}
      >
        {projects.map(({ title, details, id, img }) => {
          return (
            <ScaleBox duration={1} delayOrder={rand(1, 12)}>
              <Image
                src={img}
                alt="Picture of the author"
                width={500}
                height={500}
                loading="eager"
                priority={true}
                className={classes.img}
              />
              <Grid container className={classes.project} id="projects">
                <div>
                  <Image src="/folder.svg" width={30} height={30} alt="project" />
                </div>
                <Typography className={classes.title}>{title}</Typography>
                <Typography className={classes.details}>{details}</Typography>
      </Grid>
            </ScaleBox>
          );
        })}
    ```
    The element that I want to apply the styles is the ``classes.project`` and I added below the selector styled:
    ```
project: {
    position: 'absolute',
    // top: '25%',
    left: '55%',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    width: '600px',
    height: '230px',
    // maxWidth: '400px',
    borderRadius: '8px',
    padding: '25px',
    background: '#161e26',
    gap: 4,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    transition: 'ease 0.5s',
    zIndex: 4,
    boxShadow:
      'rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 0px 12px 28px 0px, rgb(0 0 0 / 10%) 0px 2px 4px 0px, rgb(116 116 116 / 5%) 0px 0px 0px 1px inset',
    '&:hover': {
      transform: 'translate(0, -20px)',
    },
  },
  '&:nth-child(1)': {
    top: '75%',
    zIndex: 4,
  },
  '&:nth-child(2)': {
    top: '50%',
    zIndex: 4,
  },
````

Comment: Can you also add the html? Like this it's really hard so figure out what you're doing wrong.
And I can already tell you, using `&: first-child {}` with a space after the `:` will never work, as the space is a special character in CSS selectors.

Comment: hi thank you for your reply: you can check here in pics that I took it might be easier?: 
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guroa.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1Svf.png

Comment: The images don't really help, as I can't really see on which elements the styles are being applied to (the selectors are missing)

Comment: hey @christiansany hope you had a good weekend.. I just added the JSX file if you want to have another look.. thank you very much :)

Comment: My last comment still stands... we've got not information on hat elements the styles are applied to. Pleas add the selectors (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) that you're using